# Question on abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am solving an exercise in Artin's textbook that asks us to assume, within some group $G$, that $xyz = 1$ and asks if this implies that $yxz = 1$. I've found a counterexample, but want to be sure that I'm using the language correctly.

To motivate finding the counterexample, I supposed for a contradiction that $yxz = 1$. I was able to prove that $xz = zx$. It was easy to, within the non-abelian group $S_3$ under composition, find an example where $xyz = 1$ but $yxz \neq 1$.

Here is my question: is finding that $yxz = 1$ implies that $xz = zx$ the same as finding that $yxz = 1$ implies that the group is abelian? $x$ and $z$ are arbitrary, surely, but I've added an additional assumption that $xyz = 1$. It isn't clear, for example, that I also have that $xy = yx$.

My understanding at the moment is that I have not found that the group is abelian, but rather that these particular $x$ and $z$ live in the center of the group, $Z(G)$. Is this correct?

Comment: If I understand correctly, all of these statements are only about specific elements $x$, $y$, and $z$ (rather than generic elements of $G$), and so there's no way to prove $G$ abelian using only those elements. One can replace $G$ by $G\times H$ where $H$ is nonabelian, for example, and the relations among $x,y,z=x\times e,y\times e,z\times e$ still hold.

Comment: Is it saying that we assume $xyz=1$ for all $x,y,z\in G$ or just some $x,y,z\in G$?

Comment: @Dave: The only group where $xyz=1$ for all $x,y,z\in G$ is the trivial group: take $x=y=1$ and an arbitrary $z$. The problem can’t possibly be assuming that.

Comment: If you do manage to find that $yxz = 1$ always implies $xz=zx$ *always* that would mean $yxz=1$ implies the the group is abelian because for and $xz$ you can fing $y=z^{-1}x^{-1}$ to get $yxz=1$..... But why would you care?  $yxz = 1$ *doesn't* imply $xz = zx$.  I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @fleablood: You are missing one hypothesis: the assumption being made is that *both* $xyz=1$ *and* $yxz=1$. The question is whether $xyz=1$ implies $yxz=1$. The OP is coming up with necessary conditions for $xyz=1$ to imply $yxz=1$, and found that this requires $xz=zx$. The question is whether he actually showed that $xyz=1$ *and* $yxz=1$ imply $G$ abelian (or at least whether they imply $x,z\in Z(G)$).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not the same as proving the group is abelian.

What you’ve done is show that if $xyz$ and $yxz$ are both trivial, then $x$ commutes with $z$. Nothing more, and nothing else. (Edit: Though you may be able to derive other properties about $x$, $y$, and $z$, as user750041 says in comments; but just about these elements and how they interact with each other). It does not assert that $y$ and $x$ commute, nor that $y$ and $z$ commute. You have not even shown that $x$ and $z$ are central, only that they commute *with each other*, not with everything in $G$.

Note also that “$x$ and $z$ are arbitrary” is inaccurate: they must satisfy both $xyz=1$ and $yxz=1$. That makes them *not* arbitrary!

Comment: If both $xyz=1$ and $yxz=1$, doesn't this imply that both $xy$ and $yx$ are the inverse of $z$, whence (uniqueness of the inverse) $xy=yx$?

Comment: @user750041: You are correct; I’ll edit. The point is that we are only getting conclusions about $x$, $y$, and $z$, not about $G$ or any other elements of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given the following condition:

$$\exists x,y,z \in G\mid xyz=1 \tag 1$$

Then, by $(1)$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
yxz=1 &\Rightarrow yx=z^{-1}\stackrel{(1)}{=}xy \tag 2\\
\end{alignat}

Likewise, again by $(1)$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
yxz=1 &\Rightarrow y=(xz)^{-1}=z^{-1}x^{-1} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{\Rightarrow}1=xyz=xz^{-1}x^{-1}z=(xz^{-1})(z^{-1}x)^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow xz^{-1}=z^{-1}x \\
&\Rightarrow zx=xz \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

Therefore:

$$(xyz=1 \Rightarrow yxz=1) \Rightarrow (xy=yx \wedge xz=zx)\tag 4$$

and

$$(xy=yx \vee xz=zx)\Rightarrow (xyz=1 \Rightarrow yxz=1) \tag 5$$

This has nothing to do with abelianiness, since no $\forall$ quantifier enters the discussion.